# How to make my search box work properly in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I was to search for animals details in my project but unfortunately in my controller, I do not know what to do to configure it.

```php
    public function index()
    {
        $animals =Animal::all();
        $result = false;
        if (request()->has('search') && request()->get('search') != ''){
            $result = $animals->where('serial_number', 'like', "%" .request()->get('search')."%")->get();
        }
        return view('home', ['result' => $result])->with('message', 'Below is the result');
    }
```

What am I to change
Here is my home view

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')

        <form action="{{ route('home') }}">

            <div class="p-1 bg-light rounded rounded-pill shadow-sm mb-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Here the animal serial number..." aria-describedby="button-addon1" class="form-control border-0 bg-light">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button id="button-addon1" type="submit" class="btn btn-link text-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        @if($result)
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h3>Details for the animal</h3>

                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <p><strong>Id: </strong>{{ $animal->id }}</p>
                                    <p><strong>Animal: </strong>{{ $animal->type->category }}</p>
                                    <p><strong>Gender: </strong>{{ $animal->gender }}</p>
                                    <p><strong>Place Of Birth: </strong>{{ $animal->user->address->city }}</p>
                                    <p><strong>Farm: </strong>{{ $animal->user->name }}</p>
                                    <p><strong>Date: </strong>{{ $animal->created_at }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        @endif
    @endsection
```

this is what I attempted to do until now but still getting errors like these

> "Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in /Users/macair13/MeatracProject/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php on line 30 and at least 1 expected"

Comment: Change `request()->get('search')` to `request()->query('search')`

Comment: The problem is with $result = $animals->where... . I am getting this error "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in /Users/macair13/MeatracProject/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php on line 30 and at least 1 expected".

Answer (score 0):

That is how i searched in laravel:

My form:

```
<form action="{{route('search')}}" method="post">
{{csrf_field()}}
 <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Here the animal serial number..." aria-describedby="button-addon1" class="form-control border-0 bg-light">
 <button id="button-addon1" type="submit" class="btn btn-link text-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>

</form>
```

My Web.php:

```
Route::post('search','PageController@Search')->name('search');
```

PageController:

```
public function Search(Request $request)
  {
    $serial_number= $request->input('search');
    $results =DB::table('animals')->where(function ($query) use ($serial_number) {
     $query->where('serial_number','LIKE',"%$serial_number%");
      })->latest()->get();
    return view('search',compact('results'));

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code as below

```
    public function index()
    {
        if (Input::has('search') && Input::get('search') != null){
            $result = Animal::query()->where('serial_number', 'like', "%" .Input::get('search')."%")->get();
        }else{
            $result = [];
        }
        return view('home', ['result' => $result])->with('message', 'Below is the result');
    }
```

Comment: WHat is this input class importing

Comment: both are the same, you  can use  `request()->has('search')` instead of  `Input::has('search')`

Comment: It still bringing me an error like the result is not giving me data on the page view

Comment: It is working very well but I don't understand why it is bringing me this error now "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /Users/macair13/MeatracProject/resources/views/search/index.blade.php)
" like I did not pass the variable in the right way

Comment: if you are sure that you are getting $result empty on blade try `return view('home', compact('result'));`